# Sport Association - Listing organization?

Tags: organization

I did some research but I can't find how to it. We are planning to use CIVICRM for our Wordpress Website. We want to show a page / directory of all of our Clubs (Organization). Help will be really appreciate.

Thank you very much,

Guillaume.

Comment: Are you looking for profiles? https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#displaying-information-on-public-pages

Answer (score 4):

As Demerit says, you can configure CiviCRM profiles to make search listings.

People are working on Wordpress Plugins to create views of CiviCRM data
https://civicrm.org/blog/justinfreeman/show-civicrm-content-quickly-easily-in-wordpress-using-content-views

So I guess the short answer is, yes you can. But it takes a little thought/ planning/ configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [CiviCRM Directory](https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-directory) plugin. It needs a bit of configuration and templating to make the best of it, but it works out-of-the-box for testing purposes.

Otherwise (as others have suggested) Profiles could work for you.